# How to uninstall a previously installed version of GCC on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, updates, gcc

I use Windows 10 and I think I already installed `gcc 4.9.2` with [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) IDE automatically. This is the result of `gcc --version` command on CMD:

> gcc (tdm-1) 4.9.2 Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There
>   is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
>   PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

But now I have downloaded [tdm64-gcc-5.1.0-2](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) and want to update my gcc version, but I don't know how to remove the previous version?

I installed the new version but still I get the same result from CMD line `gcc --version` command!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have downloaded tdm64-gcc-5.1.0-2 and want to update but I don't know how to remove the previous version.

If you used an installer, TDM-GCC will be listed under *Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features* and can be removed normally from there.

However, since you believe it is possible that an older version may have been included with Code::Blocks, you may wish to uninstall your current version of that program and choose a version that doesn't bundle TDM-GCC. On the [Code::Blocks downloads page](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26), the first three options (the ones that *do not* include `mingw` in the file name) are the ones you are looking for.

That said, in either case, uninstalling isn't mandatory.

For the command line, you can simply edit your Window PATH/Path variables (*Control Panel\System and Security\System → Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables...*). You can remove any references to your previous installation of TDM-GCC and add any necessary entries for your new installation.

Likewise, many IDEs allow you to specify the exact location of the compiler components you wish to use (which likely makes having TDM-GCC registered at the command line less important).

For Code::Blocks specifically, these settings are located in *Settings → Compiler...* under the *Toochain executables* tab. Note that the locations of the items under *Program Files* should all be in your TDM-GCC installation `bin` sub-directory:

[image: Code::Blocks Global Compiler Settings]

As a small suggestion, in case you are still completely clueless as to where TDM-GCC (or any other versions of `gcc.exe`) might be located, doing a Windows search for `gcc.exe` could be helpful.

Once installed correctly, your command line output should read:

> gcc (tdm64-1) 5.1.0
>
> Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
> warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`